# Https запрос в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, https

Ловлю такие ошибки

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
```

когда пытаюсь сделать GET запрос на HTTPS, нагуглил про openSSL, куда и как его верно поставить? В интернете информация только о старых версиях Qt, пробывал сделать по ним, ничего не вышло

Comment: Сорри по привычке ты поставил openSSL, какая os gnu/linux или windows?

Comment: А почему вы не используете обычные qt средства - QNetworkManager и QNetworkReply?

Answer (score 1):

Приложение не видит библиотеки openssl, чтобы оно её увидило, нужно либо добавить путь к библиотекам в PATH, либо положить библиотеки рядом с приложением(бинарным файлом)

Answer (score 0):

Зайди на http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
Скачай НЕ последнюю, в последней не нашел нужных библиотек, может просто теперь по-другому нызвается. Скачай версию light.
Скопируй libeay32.dll и ssleay32.dll туда же где у тебя модуль QtNetwork<4/5>.dll. (обычно папка Qt/ версия Qt-а/ компилятор / bin)

Взято отсюда http://codeblog.vurdalakov.net/2009/11/solution-qsslsocket-cannot-call.html . Мне помогло.